# MS Access SQL IIF optimization

Tags: sql, ms-access, query-optimization

Given this table, I have a query that uses IIF to pull out the value from one column when the other one is NULL.

```
COL_A,COL_B
NULL,10
12,NULL
14,NULL
NULL,16

SELECT iif(COL_A IS NULL, COL_B, COL_A);

Results:
10
12
14
16
```

What I'm trying to work out is how to do this in straight SQL. Is there a way this can be done? Normally I wouldn't mind using this a few times, but we have a massive query with *cough* 86 IIF statements and it's getting prohibitive to run. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`NZ()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php)

```
 select nz(COL_A, COL_B)
```

Comment: What about if you're testing more than one field to see if it's null?

Comment: @DanChampagne - *nz(nz(COL_A, COL_B), COL_C)*

Comment: The question is how to optimize a query with 86 seperate IIF's, changing them to Nz shouldn't significantly improve that.

Answer (score 1):

If your query needs to carry out 86 different test's in one query then I would suggest the data architecture is flawed, you could shorten down your SQL by writing a custom function using the "Case" method which could step through all the validation and return a result. However this will only improve the look of your SQL and won't really improve performance.  Difficult to say without a list of the 86 IIF's but I think you need to look at your data structure to see if you can improve things from table level.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only one column will have an actual value, You could just Concatenate them, since the nulls would compress.
Select `COL_A||COL_B||COL_C||COL_D||....`

Comment: +1 for the concept.  With Access' db engine, use an ampersand instead of the vertical bars for concatenation:  `Select COL_A & COL_B & COL_C & COL_D & ....`